# neg_mean_squared_error in cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, mse

The string `"mean_squared_error"` appears to be deprecated in `cross_val_score` now, and it's saying to use `neg_mean_squared_error`. Is this metric literally just the negative of the MSE?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, `neg_mean_squared_error` is simple `-1 * mean_squared_error`. This is because a convention in the [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) api that all the scorers follow.

According to scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) (some emphasis added):

> For the most common use cases, you can designate a scorer object with the scoring parameter; the table below shows all possible values. **All scorer objects follow the convention that higher return values are better than lower return values.** Thus metrics which measure the distance between the model and the data, like `metrics.mean_squared_error`, are available as `neg_mean_squared_error` which return the **negated** value of the **metric**.

Comment: When it says "higher return values are better than lower return values,"  does this mean "higher in MAGNITUDE?" If not, then for negative values, smaller in magnitude would mean "higher."

Comment: You cannot have negative values in the mean squared error by definition ``mean(y - y_hat)**2`` will always be positive, so in principle, the higher the worst the model is, when multiplied by -1 the magnitude is inverted so that higher values will imply a better fit, and as above states, this is only for metrics that measure the distance between the model and the data